# MacBook Pro Mid 2009 shows forbidden sign but boots when holding command key

Tags: macos, high-sierra, startup, diskutil

After upgrading from High Sierra 10.13.x (can't remember) to High Sierra 10.13.6, something went wrong with the boot partition. When turned on the MacBook shows the forbidden sign. However when I press and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, it boots normally. So far so good, however in macOS safari and chrome are only showing blank pages, so I guess I re-install of macOS is a good idea. In order to do that you need to press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> during boot, but when I press anything more than <kbd>Command</kbd> only, the forbidden sign shows again.

fdisk shows:

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 19457/255/63 [312581808 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
     Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -  312581807] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Diskutil shows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *160.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Heinen                  159.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.
Gerben

Comment: Have you tried doing a PRAM reset https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063

Comment: Unfortunately, pressing anything else than only the command key during startup, results in the forbidden sign and nothing happens after that.

Comment: How did you manage to install High Sierra when your model Mac is to old? See [macOS High Sierra - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP765?locale=en_US).

Comment: it's not too old, it worked. Any ideas on my fix?